# Setting $PS4 using `bash -c`

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to set `$PS4` for a `bash -c` command. Example:

```
bash -xc 'PS4='$(date "+%s.%N ($LINENO) + ")'; echo ABC; echo XYZ'
```

I've tried escaping the quotes, dollar signs and brackets in a variety of ways to no success.

The output I would expect is this, which can be obtained with a shell script that has a `/bin/bash -x` shebang, and the `$PS4` definition:

```
#!/bin/bash -x 

PS4='$(date "+%s.%N ($LINENO) + ")'
echo ABC
echo XYZ
```

which yields:

```
...
11527777373.733823550 (4) + echo ABC
11527777373.754886273 (5) + echo XYZ
...
```

How can I achieve similarly for the `bash -c ...` command?

Comment: BTW, running a subshell and calling the external `date` command inside it is going to require enough time that any nanosecond-level timing is going to be very badly thrown off by the overhead needed to spawn the subshell and run `date` inside it. With a modern bash having `printf %(...)T -1` you can get much higher-performance time-formatting (though not in the context of a `PS4` -- a `DEBUG` trap would work, though); caveat is that it only provides `strftime` format strings, which don't portably support nanoseconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use `$'...'` quoting, which allows embedded single quotes:

```
bash -xc $'PS4=\'+ $(date "+%s.%N ($LINENO) ")\'; echo ABC; echo XYZ'
```

If you can live without nanosecond resolution, I recommend using the `\D` prompt escape instead of `date`:

```
bash -xc $'PS4=\'+ \\D{%s} ($LINENO) \'; echo ABC; echo XYZ'
```

---

Note that you can simplify the quoting by passing the value via the environment, although for security reasons this won't work if `bash` is run as root. (`bash` will simply ignore any value of `PS4` found in the environment.)

```
PS4='+ \D{%s} ($LINENO) ' bash -xc 'echo ABC; echo XYZ'
```

Comment: One caveat -- the through-the-environment approach doesn't work with very recent bash when run as root, due to fixes implemented to work around CVE-2016-7543

Comment: Ugh, yeah. I had too many ideas running through my head involving using `\D` instead of `date`, then switched back to `date` at the last second when I noticed the `%N` format.

Comment: It's probably worth showing the OP how to use `\D`, with an explanation of why they should consider doing so -- using a nanosecond-scale format with something that has enough overhead to totally throw off those numbers isn't generally very useful.

Comment: Fabulous answer! I was trying to remember the syntax for how to do this and for the life of me couldn't think what that type of escaping is called. Could you put a name to it for me?

Comment: @NickBull, [the bash-hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) documents it as "ANSI C-like strings"

Comment: @chepner, ...err, inside `$''`, shouldn't it be `\\D` to avoid relying on undefined behavior?

Comment: %$#^%$. Yes. :) That's the other reason I wanted to pass the value via the environment.

Comment: Personally, I'd restructure this answer with the `PS4=... bash -xc ...` example first. Aside from the caveat that it doesn't work for root-run scripts it's clearer and simpler than the examples given earlier in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness (adding to the [already-quite-good answer from chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50627236/14122)), you can use a quoted heredoc to get code into a variable without modification; expanding that variable in a double-quoted context will then pass its contents through literally:

```
cmd=$(cat <<'EOF'
PS4='+ $(date "+%s.%N ($LINENO) ")'
echo ABC
echo XYZ
EOF
)

bash -xc "$cmd"
```